# parse.com includeKey: not working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

The problem i have is very strange. I query this table:

with this class:

[image]

```
class ParseFriend: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

override class func load() {

    self.registerSubclass()

}

class func parseClassName() -> String! {

    return "Friend"

}

@NSManaged var fromUser: ParseUser!

@NSManaged var toUser: ParseUser!

@NSManaged var status: NSNumber!



}
```

And here where i create the request:

```
    let fromQuery = ParseFriend.query()

    fromQuery.whereKey("toUser", equalTo: ParseUser.currentUser())

    fromQuery.includeKey("fromUser")

    let toQuery = ParseFriend.query()

    toQuery.whereKey("fromUser", equalTo: ParseUser.currentUser())

    toQuery.includeKey("toUser")

    let orQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([fromQuery, toQuery])

    orQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results, error) -> Void in

        println("this is never called")

    }
```

For some reason "this is never called" only gets executed if i remove "includeKey" from both queries and works as expected. Any ideas? I get no error, just jumps the completion block.
I notice if i put a randomly key in includeKey i get the same scenario. And those users exists in the User table.

Answer (score -1):

Use includeKey in the orQuery instead of individual PFQuerys